# Explosion effect is getting stopped by domain

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, fire

When i make my explosion, everything is good, but when it builds up, the smoke reaches the walls of the domain, causing it to stop there. I made the explosion from a video and in order to ask, i joined the youtuber's discord server, where they told me to expand the domain and bake it again. But that makes my explosion bigger, it doesnt give it more space. Do you have any advice?[image]

Comment: Did you scale and bake sim again or scaled and played only? There is sometimes issue -sim use previously stored cache. Also to get the same amount of details you will need to increase domain resolution accordingly.

Comment: @vklidu I scaled up, baked, saw its not good, let all free, rescaled, baked again and so on. I know about the resolution, my pc isnt so good, thats why i sacrifice some quality for some better fps

Comment: Experiment with "adaptive domain". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29yfS-icS3M

Comment: @FilipFranik Thank you, i use the same video of Iridesium for making the explosion. Now when i was waiting for answer, i tried to experiment with adaptive domain, it seamed like it would do the job. Now after you confirmed that this is the way to go, i will keep on experimenting with it.

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 I'm also just a beginner, but I successfully followed exactly that tutorial using adaptive domain.

Comment: @FilipFranik i did as well, i just cant make my explosion be free in my domain, each time i resize my domain, it resizes the explosion as well, it doesnt give it more space,which is what i want

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 upload your blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I had to increase the "add resolution" property under adaptive domain and decrease "threshold" to .01

Answer (score 0):

Make a cube then scale it. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Apply > Scale*.

Then turn it into a fluid, domain type. Finally increase the resolution. In the *Shader Editor*, use the *Principled Volume* and connect it to the *Volume* to be displayed in the rendering.